# Can I only view local or remote branches in the tree view?

Tags: gitkraken

I have too many remote branches in the track for the tree view, but I only want to view my local branches in the tree. Is there an option to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,
In the `REMOTE` section on the left side (where you can see origin branches),
[image]

hover your mouse above the empty square next to the origin icon like that:
[image]

And click the green eye icon ("Hide in the graph") which make your remote branches hidden and the icon will be changed to:
[image]

By the way, you can hide and show like that every single branch (local and remote) as well.